# Página de erro no AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Bom, sou novo para AngularJS. Eu tenho um projeto, uma única página com rotas configuradas com um controlador. As views são carregados dentro do   elemento da página index.html. Dentro do controlador Eu estou fazendo uma chamada http para obter os dados e ligação de dados com o $ escopo. Conforme jogo o módulo, ele é aplicado na ng-view. Até ai tudo bem.. porém necessito fazer uma página de erro, caso o usuário acesse na url qualquer coisa que não seja encontrada, seja direcionado para uma página de erro.. onde posso personalizar o erro e sugerir para o usuário voltar a página principal.

Comment: Tu tá se referindo pra tratar o erro 404?

Comment: Isso, quando alguém digitar algo na url que não exista.. ou ocorrer algum erro seja em cadastro ou algo pertinente, para ter uma view personalizada do erro..

Comment: Quem trata requisição é o teu servidor, seja ASP ou PHP ou qualquer outro. Por exemplo no PHP se faz isso usando o `httpd`. O angular não vai conseguir fazer isso, a menos é claro que tu quer tratar se o retorno da `ng-route` veio vazio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Caso você esteja utilizando angular-ui/ui-router, o provedor `$urlRouter` oferece a possibilidade de configuração da rota de *fallback* durante o estágio `config` - que é utilizada sempre que o usuário tenta acessar uma rota não configurada:

```
app.config(
    function ($urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/notFound");
    });
```

(O exemplo acima assume que `/notFound` é sua rota de tratamento para página não encontrada.)

A vantagem deste método é que você pode implementar um estado sem *Url*, permitindo assim que a URL originalmente informada pelo usuário seja mantida na barra de navegação. Exemplo:

```
    $stateProvider.
        state("notFound", {
            templateUrl: "statusNotFound.html",
            controller:
                function ($scope, $http) {
                        // Seu código aqui
                    });
                }
        });
```

Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Você pode inserir o seguinte código nas suas rotas. Quando não encontrar uma rota válida, ele redireciona para a rota /404

```js
$routeProvider
.when('/home', {template: homeTemplate})
.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/404'
});
```